# Block user redirection to wp-login.php on leaving password blank in frontend login

Tags: wordpress, function, authentication

When a user leaves the Username / Password / Both Blank and clicks login in frontend buddypress login, he is being redirected to wordpress admin login url stating wrong username/password/empty warning. How can i redirect user to an otherpage when he leaves the Username / Password / Both Blank.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not pretty, taken & modified from http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-login-hints-in-wordpress-login-error-messages/:

```
function no_wordpress_errors(){
  return header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
  exit;
}
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'no_wordpress_errors' );
```

Add this in your theme's `functions.php` or plugin file, and someone who uses incorrect credentials gets redirected to example.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this Plugin. It provides great features when logging IN/OUT:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/